# XML Parsing Error: mismatched tag. Expected: </r> how to handle?

Tags: c#, xml

I am xml parsing but i getting  issue on load xml file on browser

Its going to search closing tag of `</r>`. but it can not find, so it return error

error look like:

```
XML Parsing Error: mismatched tag. Expected: </r>.
```

XML look like:

```
<shortdescription>Format : VCD<r>Language : English</shortdescription>
```

how to handle this situation pls give me idea.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Your XML is not correctly formated. There's an opening `<r>` tag but the closing `</r>` tag is missing. Remove the `<r>` tag or add the `</r>` tag or surround the text in a CDATA tag.

Comment: i know </r> tag not closing in my xml but how to handle in c#. because i am not able to editing xml file

Comment: The XML parser is telling you that your XML cannot be parsed because it's not valid. I don't know what you want to do. If it's not valid, it cannot be (easily) parsed. You could write a custom parser but I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: `CDATA` will provide a general solution here.

Comment: @AndreiV my xml was parse successfully but when we open in firefox getting error.

Comment: @GrantWinney i have also use &lt;r&gt; but not work for me it returns same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is not well-formed XML, therefore the XML parser is doing the right thing by raising an error.

What would you do if there were a syntax error in your C# program? There's only one thing to do, fix it. If at all possible, fix the program or process that generates this bad data. If that's not possible, write a repair program to patch it up; but somehow, given the question, I suspect that's a task beyond your level of experience.